# Relative syzygies in a given selfinjective algebra

Tags: rt.representation-theory

Let $A$ be a selfinjective finite dimensional algebra and $M$ an indecomposable non-projective module. Let $N=A \oplus M$. Then a minimal right add(N)-approximation of a module is defined as a map $f:N' \rightarrow X$ with $N' \in add(N)$ such that $Hom(N,f)$ is surjective and such that $f$ is right minimal, meaning that there is no nonzero indecomposable summand $Y$ of $N'$ which is mapped to zero. Let $\Omega_N^{1}(X)$ denote the kernel of such an $f$ and define $\Omega_N^{i+1}(X)=\Omega_N^{i}(\Omega_N^{1}(X))$, called the $i+1$-th relative syzygy.
Now special sitation: Let $c$ be a nonzero field element and $A=K[x,y]/(x^2,y^2,xy-cyx)$ and $M_{a,b}=A/(ax+by)A$ and $N_{a,b}=A \oplus M_{a,b}$ for two non-zero field elements $a,b$.
Can one determine the $i$-th relative syzygy of an arbitrary indecomposable $A$-module in a nice way? Or at least in the case when $X=M_{f,g}$ for some nonzero field elements $f,g$.

Comment: It may be a good idea to ask this sort of questions on math.stackexchange.com

Comment: I doubt the general question has an easy answer, but feel free to prove me wrong.

Comment: Have you tried to find the first syzygy in your example?

Comment: Just for special choices of $f$ and $g$. It seems to depend wheter Ext^1 between the modules vanishes.